# How to create a Google OAuth 2 Authorization to grant access to my Google Cloud endpoint custom API?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-oauth

I don't understand the google's doc about OAuth authorization. It's seems to be set to grant access to the google APIs such as Google  Plus, Google Contacts etc.

However, my goal is to set an authorization process to grant access to some parts of my own application via my custom API built with google cloud endpoint.

The process should be simple. Just like on facebook or twitter API, a third party user/application come on my web server and request for a token to be allowed to do some operations in my app.

So my API generate the token automatically each time a user making the request.

Not to access google services but my own app.

All tutorials in the google docs seems to cover Oauth2 authorization for google API and not for custom Google cloud endpoints API.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some annotations to your Endpoints API. The `scopes` and `clientIds` parameters are used for OAuth2 authorization. See [the Java docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/add-authorization-backend) or [the Python docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/auth) for auth. The docs describe adding the support in both the API and for clients.